# saving an swf to two different directories in Flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

This seems impossible directly from flash, but if there are any other suggestions, I'd love to hear them

I want to compile an FLA that I want to use as resources for two slightly different application in two different folders.

something like this

> library.FLA
>
> -> bin1/lib.swf
>
> AND
>
> -> bin2/lib.swf

any ideas?

I could just copy them manually, but with multiple files there's always room to forget one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well for now I've created a batch file

```
SET PATH=%CD%

COPY %PATH%\lib\*.swf %PATH%\..\Dir1\bin\lib\
COPY %PATH%\lib\*.swf %PATH%\..\Dir2\bin\lib\
COPY %PATH%\lib\*.swf %PATH%\..\Dir3\bin\lib\
COPY %PATH%\lib\*.swf %PATH%\..\Dir4\bin\lib\

PAUSE
```

Although I've shown the path as %CD% I'm actually using the full path in my batch file because the directory is on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a symlink. 
In the command line, provided that bin1 & bin2 are on the same level , you would need to navigate inside the bin2 folder and write:

```
 ln -s ../bin1/lib.swf
```